# Huge gap in UI when using columns

Tags: scripting

I want to create buttons designed like this:

[image]

But as you can see, there is a huge gap after the buttons, but I don't know how to get rid of it. Here is the code I use:

```
    layout = self.layout
    box = layout.box()
    col = box.column(align=True)

    col.separator()
    row = col.row(align=True)
    row.scale_y = 2
    row.operator('translate.all', text='All', icon='META_BALL')

    subcol = row.column(align=True)
    subcol.operator('translate.shapekeys', text='Shape Keys', icon='SHAPEKEY_DATA')
    subcol.operator('translate.objects', text='Objects', icon='MESH_DATA')

    subcol = row.column(align=True)
    subcol.operator('translate.bones', text='Bones', icon='BONE_DATA')
    subcol.operator('translate.materials', text='Materials', icon='MATERIAL')
```

I tested it with row.row instead of row.column and it got rid of the gap, but it's no longer the design I want:

[image]

How can I fix this? Thanks!

**Edit:** This problem got fixed here: https://blenderartists.org/t/huge-gap-in-ui-when-using-columns/1121436/6